# Implementing a image gallery in Phoenix Framework (Elixir)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to implement a image gallery using arc.
I am facing the following problems

1. Cannot upload multiple files at a time ( to AWS S3 )
2. Can upload file which is less than an mb, get a timeout error if I try large files ( would like to know how to upload large files )
3. Displaying images from AWS S3

The Error that I get while uploading a file more than an MB is

```
[error] Task #PID<0.536.0> started from #PID<0.533.0> terminating
** (stop) {:aws_error, {:socket_error, :timeout}}
    (erlcloud) src/erlcloud_s3.erl:911: :erlcloud_s3.s3_request/8
    (erlcloud) src/erlcloud_s3.erl:611: :erlcloud_s3.put_object/6
    (arc) lib/arc/storage/s3.ex:9: Arc.Storage.S3.put/3
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:74: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:19: Task.Supervised.async/3
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: #Function<2.64561725/0 in Arc.Actions.Store.async_put_version/3>
    Args: []
[error] Ranch protocol #PID<0.533.0> (:cowboy_protocol) of listener Pxblog.Endpoint.HTTP terminated
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ErlangError) erlang error: {:aws_error, {:socket_error, :timeout}}
        (erlcloud) src/erlcloud_s3.erl:911: :erlcloud_s3.s3_request/8
        (erlcloud) src/erlcloud_s3.erl:611: :erlcloud_s3.put_object/6
        (arc) lib/arc/storage/s3.ex:9: Arc.Storage.S3.put/3
        (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:74: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
        (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:19: Task.Supervised.async/3
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

I am following the [arc upload](https://github.com/stavro/arc) library

Following is the create function for controller

```
def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params, "images" => images_params}) do
    changeset = Post.changeset(%Post{}, post_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _post} ->

        images = images_params

        current_user = %{id: 1}

        Enum.count(images, fn(image) -> Image.store({image, current_user}) end)

      conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Post created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: post_path(conn, :index))

      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

The Arc Library gives a method **MyApp.Avatar.url()** but when I try to call it in the show template, for example **MyApp.Avatar.url(@user.avatar, @user)** it says the function is not defined.

Comment: Start by putting all the code you have so far regarding these questions and then people will be able to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arc` is too new and I think you'd be better off implementing all the things that you need by yourself. There is nothing difficult with sending commands to `ImageMagick` or whatever you're using to transform the images  and then you could simply use the `ex_aws` package (or `erlcloud`, whichever you like more) to send all kinds of requests that AWS S3 API supports, it will probably take less time to implement this than to fight with `arc`.

But getting back to your question, I've noticed that there is this line:

```
current_user = %{id: 1}
```

and it's just a map and you probably need to use a user's struct, so it would be something like that:

```
current_user = Repo.get(User, 1)
```

Aside from that, as rorra said, more code needed to see what may be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

> Cannot upload multiple files at a time ( to AWS S3 )

Elixir has concurrency convenience modules just for this reason!  Start up multiple tasks.  Example:

```
images = []

images
|> Enum.map(fn(image) -> async_upload(image, current_user) end)
|> Enum.each(fn(task) -> Task.await(task, 60_000) end)

defp async_upload(image) do
  Task.async(fn ->
    Image.store({image, current_user})
  end)
end
```

> Can upload file which is less than an mb, get a timeout error if I try large files ( would like to know how to upload large files )

The timeout in Arc is now configurable, which can be boosted.  This is by default 15 seconds.

```
config :arc,
  version_timeout: 15_000 #milliseconds
```

> Displaying images from AWS S3

I'm not sure what the issue is here.. But if you feel there is something wrong please open an issue on [Arc](https://github.com/stavro/arc/issues).

Disclaimer: Author of `Arc`

Comment: Thanks, Sean, This method works!, about Displaying the images I wanted to know How can I retrieve the images for a user?